# Confirm When User Navigates Away from Page While File is Uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

I am using a multiple file upload scenario based on blueimp ([http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)) and Ruby on Rails GEM Carrierwave. The issue that I am having is that a user can navigate away from the webpage prior to the uploading of files finishes. I am trying to create a way that if the file is currently being uploaded and the user navigates away from the page prior to the uploading finishes then it should return a confirmation dialogue. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added to the end of the form that is handling the file uploading.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if ($('#fileupload').data('fileupload')._active) {
        return 'Leaving now would abort your upload. Are you sure?';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with Javascript's [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) event.

```
var upload_pending = false;

// ...

// Once upload has started, toggle the boolean flag (in something like
// a click event on the submit button for the form with the file field, 
// making sure to toggle it back after the upload finishes
upload_pending = true;

// ...

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  if (!upload_pending) return;

  // For IE<8 and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'There is a pending upload.';
  }

  // For Chrome, Safari, IE8+ and Opera 12+
  return 'There is a pending upload.';
};
```

Comment: Thanks Deefour, this is really good information, but I think that I may have found a solution that requires less work since the BlueImp File Upload script already contains an active status when uploading files.